# Java: Am I over-simplifying the code?

Tags: java

This is a toy example problem that I created. I have a `IP` class. And I want to create an arraylist of `IP` like the following, but it didn't work.

```
class IP{
     private long d;
     public IP(long d){
          this.d = d;
     }
}

class something{
     public void some_method(){
         HashMap<IP, ArrayList<IP>> ip_map = new HashMap<IP,ArrayList<IP>>();
         ......
         IP ip_key = new IP(1);
         IP ip2 = new IP(2);
         IP ip3 = new IP(3);
         // this is the line that always goes wrong
         ip_map.put(ip_key, new ArrayList<IP>(ip2)) ;
         ip_map.get(ip_key).add(ip3);
     }
}
```

This always fails. The error message is:

```
error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(IP)
                ip_map.put(ip_key, new ArrayList<IP>(ip2));
                                   ^
    constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; IP cannot be converted to int)
    constructor ArrayList.ArrayList() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(Collection<? extends Vertex>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; IP cannot be converted to Collection<? extends IP>)
1 error
```

Is it because my IP class is not not implementing the Collection interface ? I would like to know if this is actually infeasible: `ip_map.put(ip_key, new ArrayList<IP>(ip2)) ;`

**UPDATE:** I know I can overcome this by

```
ArrayList<IP> ip_list = new ArrayList<IP>();
ip_list.add(ip2);
ip_map.put(ip_key, ip_list);
```

BUT I want to know if it is possible to do it like the following because of code reduction?

```
ip_map.put(ip_key, new ArrayList<IP>(ip2)) ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you intend to do with `new ArrayList<IP>(ip2)`? If you want to create a list with `ip2` in it, you need to instantiate the list, and then add it. Like:

```
List<IP> list = new ArrayList<IP>();
list.add(ip2)
```

Check the java doc for `new ArrayList(int)` constructor [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to learn what ArrayList(ip2) will try to do and why it fails.

If you really want to shorten (not simplify really) your code, you can do:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
...
...
List<IP> list = new ArrayList<IP>(Arrays.asList(ip2));
```

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I know I can do it in your way. But I want to simplify my code.

Comment: I added a way in which you can do it, but it is just unnecessary in my opinion. The usual two line way is more readable

Answer (score 1):

The collection constructors do not support individual elements or arrays, as those are no collections in the API sense. You can either pass a collection to initially populate the new collection with or a number indicating the initial capacity that is internally allocated.

If you are looking for an efficient representation of unmodifiable collections with a single element, have a look at `Collections.singleton(T)`, `Collections.singletonList(T)` or `Collections.singletonMap(K, V)`.